# Nested entities contains null after save

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with some nested entities like this

```
public class MyEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_ENTITY2")
    private Entity2 fkEntity2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_ENTITY3")
    private Entity3 fkEntity3;
}
```

with entity2 and entity3 like this:

```
public class Entity2/3{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   
   @Column(name = "code")
   private String code;
   
   @Column(name = "desc")
   private String desc;

   //getter and setter etc
}
```

Both `Entity2` and `Entity3` have values stored in the database so when I'm doing an insert on `MyEntity`, I'm doing this:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public MyService {
  //idFromController and otherIdFromController refers to existent records in the database
  public MyDto save(Long idFromController, Long otherIdFromController){
    Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
    entity2.setId(idFromController);

    Entity3 entity3 = new Entity3();
    entity3.setId(otherIdFromController);

    MyEntity newMyEntity = new MyEntity();
    newMyEntity.setEntity2(entity2);
    newMyEntity.setEntity3(entity3);

    MyEntity result = myEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(newMyEntity);

    return getDto(result);
  }

}
```

it works fine, the data are stored correctly in the DB with the correct foreign keys BUT...
After insert I want to build a DTO which contains id, code and desc from the nested entities so something like this:

```
private MyDto getDto(MyEntity result){
  MyDto dto = new MyDto();
  dto.setId2(result.getEntity2().getId()); 
  dto.setCode2(result.getEntity2().getCode()); 
  dto.setDesc2(result.getEntity2().getDesc()); 

  dto.setId3(result.getEntity3().getId()); 
  dto.setCode3(result.getEntity3().getCode()); 
  dto.setDesc3(result.getEntity3().getDesc()); 
}
```

Here is the problem, I only got the id fields and null on code and description.

When I call `getDto()` in a search it works and every field has the correct values, so it is something related to the insert transaction? how could I solve this?

Comment: Set break points and debug...

Comment: I assume, your code is incomplete.. e.g. do you have all the necessary classes annotated with `@Entity`?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. Entities are pojos, so if you aren't populating the values in the Entity3/Entity2 instances you are associating to the new MyEntity, you get that same MyEntity instance and its references back. You would need to refresh the instances from the database to force reloading. Try em.refresh(myEntity) and return the result instead, but you are better off reading in entity2/3 instances using a find call and using that to set the references before the saveAndFlush call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the DTO, the (existing) entities are not attached to the persistence context, so the corresponding data has not been loaded from the DB and cannot be copied to the DTO.

One option would be to load the entities e.g. via 'myRepository.findById...' and associate the returned (managed) entities.

Comment: with findById used on the nested entity I was able to retrieve the data, I'm going to investigate more and try to understand if it's possible to refresh the entity in the persistence context

Answer (score 1):

you missed some part of the many-to-one relation. first in  `MyEntity` class it was better to define a fetch type. in `Entity2` and `Entity3` you need to define `@OneToMany` as the other side of the relation with declaration of fetch type and `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` which simply tells to hibernate what it can do with relative entity when you are doing save, delete ,update. I reformat your code as following

```
public class Entity2/3{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   
   @Column(name = "code")
   private String code;
   
   @Column(name = "desc")
   private String desc;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy ="fkEntity2",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Entity2> entityTwoList;
// for Entity3
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy ="fkEntity3",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Entity3> entityThreeList;

public class MyEntity {
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_ENTITY2")
    private Entity2 fkEntity2;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_ENTITY3")
    private Entity3 fkEntity3;
}
}
```